# Form a query to find duplicate zipcodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a zipcode table. I want to look through this table and find every zipcode that is in it twice. The table does have a primary key set on it(zipcode_rid). How would I do this?

Also, I am aware that there are official multi-state/city/county zipcodes. That is what I'm wishing to find.

My table structure is like so:

- zipcode_rid (int, unique, primary key)
- zipcode (int)
- city (varchar(50))
- state (varchar(50))
- county (varchar(50))

The database software I am using is Sql Server 2008 Express

Comment: Side note: zipcode's are not strictly integral. They have significant leading zeros, and you're obviously disregarding ZIP+4, which can lead to delayed mail delivery. Also, this format inherently makes your software US-only.

Comment: Note, that this criticism comes into play because I've seen the USPS send priority parcels to the wrong side of the country due to a misspelled street name with only 5-digit ZIP, while the same misspelled street name with correct ZIP+4 made it on time directly to the correct address.

Comment: @Nathan it is more for "where do you live at" purposes than "we're sending you stuff in the mail" so it's really irrelevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a query that gives you all the zip codes that occur in the table twice. You can change the "= 2" portion to be "> 1" or whathaveyou. I've included the COUNT() in there because if you use ">1" you can see exactly how many times it appears.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(zipcode_rid) AS No_of_Zipcodes
    ,zipcode
FROM
    Zipcodes
GROUP BY
    zipcode
HAVING
    COUNT(zipcode_rid) = 2
```

Comment: If there's more than two duplicates, the zipcode won't be displayed if you use `HAVING COUNT(..) = 2`

Comment: @OMG Ponies - His question asked to see zipcodes that appeared in there twice. I also added the info about "> 1" to see those that appear in there twice, or more than twice.

Comment: Both of you are correct, but @OMG didn't include the `count` selection which makes this marginally better.. plus I like giving rep to the guys with <20k of rep :)

Answer (score 9):

To get a list of zipcodes with duplicates, use:

```
  SELECT t.zipcode
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.zipcode
  HAVING COUNT(t.zipcode) > 1
```